# "Tutto quello che" o "tutto ciò che"

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, grammar

Why *tutto quello che* and not *tutto ciò che* in this example?

> Questo è tutto quello che ho di più caro.

Can we say

> Questo è tutto ciò che ho di più caro.

Why *tutto ciò che* and not *quello che* in this example?

> Ho tutto ciò che mi serve.

Can we translate with "I have everything I need"?

Can we in both cases replace with *quanto*?

> Ho quanto mi serve.

> Questo è quanto ho di più caro.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: I think all the phrases are correct and none of them sounds strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Questo è tutto quello che ho di più caro.

is the same as

> Questo è tutto ciò che ho di più caro.

In the first two examples both forms are correct

> Ho tutto ciò che mi serve

is equal to

> Ho tutto quello che mi serve

you can use whatever you want

The translation "I have everything I need" is correct

I confirm that the replacement of "Quanto" is possible and perfectly applied

Answer (score 1):

Grammaticaly, "tutto [ciò](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cio/)" can be translated to "all this/all that".

Instead - "tutto [quello](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quello/)" becomes only "all that", indicating that something is far from who's speaking.

---

- **"Ho tutto ciò che mi serve."** >> "I have everything I need.
- **"Ho quello che mi serve."** >> "I have what I need.

The only thing that is making these two sentences differ is the "**tutto**". Removing it, both sentences would have the same meaning.

---

**"Ho quanto mi serve."**, **"Questo è quanto ho di più caro."**

> Can we in both cases replace with quanto?

To answer your question: yes, both phrases are correct.